# How can I validate data returned from a WCF service, against xsd schema files that define what the service should conform to

Tags: xml, xsd, wcf, xsd-validation

I have some XSD files and a WSDL provided by the customer.  I have built a WCF service.  I would like to show that the service is compliant with the provided schemas. How can I validate my WCF service against those schemas?  I have SoapUI and Altova XML Spy if that helps. What is the standard way to do this? I did not build this with the schema first approach.

Comment: One thing to consider is that you can only validate the data that your service actually sends - you will need a test suite to cause it to send all of the possible responses.

Answer (score -1):

Use this to pass XML and XSD. This applies to any XML and Sxhema and not specific to web services:

```
    private static void ValidateSchema(string xmlName, string schemaName)
    {

        try
        {
            ValidationEventHandler validationHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);
            XmlTextReader schemaReader = new XmlTextReader( schemaName);
            XmlSchema schema =XmlSchema.Read(schemaReader, validationHandler);

            XmlTextReader docReader = new XmlTextReader (xmlName);
            XmlValidatingReader vr = new XmlValidatingReader( docReader); 
            vr.Schemas.Add (schema);  
            vr.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            vr.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler( ValidationCallBack);

            try 
            {
                while (vr.Read())
                {
                ;   //Console.Write(" {0} = \"{1}\";", vr.Name, vr.Value);
                }
            }

            catch 
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Validation error!");

            }
        }


        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex); 
        }

    }

    private static void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Validation Error: {0}", e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
    }       

}
```

Comment: He is after verifying the XML output against an XSD. It will require removing SOAP header and envelope if Schema in WSDL does not have that but it will work.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this is all helpful to me, but unfortunately I need something that a non-programmer would use.  Something for some of our QA people.  ~ck